# is there opencv matrix multiplication limits in size?

Tags: opencv

I am multiplying two big matrices of size 360x25600 and 25600x360.
A error occurs as memory access violation.

```
a - size of 360x25600
b - size of 25600x360

cv::Mat L_mat;

cv::Multiply(a,b,L_mat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::muliply` is element-wise multiplication.  You want `operator *`.